# EntityFramework inheritance - Ignore not nullable column

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, orm

I have an one entity in my edmx model having an one property that can contains huge XML data.

Basically I  want to load this entity without this property (column)  /* huge data loading  */ . And load this column only when it is strictly needed.

I have tried to create an inherited entity containing this property and remove this property from base entity (original entity). I have done mapping.
At this time I have problem, that during compilation a I get error, that base entity is not capable to insert and update itself, because property is not nullable

I am looking for best approach (solution) how this situation should be solved.

I am attaching the cut-out from my emdx designer (containing my current and desired situation)

[image: EntityFrameWork view]

**UPDATE:**

I will try to write a procedure that I have tried:
I mapped functions to my custom functions. For entity TRP_TechReport_T without the XML column (property). Then I just mapped for entity TRP_TechReport_T functions to my custom function (containing XML column).

Then I set Mapping condition on the entity TRP_TechReport_T:  When TRP_XML = Empty.String

TechReport_T mappings:
[image: TechReport mappings]

TechReport_T functions:
[image]

TechReportFull_T mappings:
[image: Entity TechReportFull_T mappings]

TechReportFull_T functions:
[image: TechReportFull_T functions]

At this moment I get error:

> Error 2   Error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 3754:Condition member 'TRP_TechReport_T.TRP_XML' with a condition other than 'IsNull=False' is mapped. Either remove the condition on TRP_TechReport_T.TRP_XML or remove it from the mapping.

The column is not nullable in the database and mustn't be.

I can hard-set XML property to nullable, but in the case of the model updating from the database information will be lost.

At the moment it's the only thing I could think of.

Comment: Have a look at [Entity Framework lazy loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647931/entity-framework-lazy-loading)